# How to convert list of lists into tuples in Haskell, adding some specifications

Tags: haskell

I have a list of lists : `[[43525,3,2],[43615,2,2],[41111,1,2],[74855,5,3]]`
I want to convert this list into a list of tuples, taking only the second and the last elements of every list. And adding `15*i` every time I map on the list (`i` is the index).

taking the first example:
`[[43525,3,2],[43615,2,2],[41111,1,2],[74855,5,3]]`
I want somthing like :
`[(3,2) , (17, 2), (31, 2), (50, 3)]`

`17 = 3+(15*1)`
`31 = 1+(15*2)`
`50 = 5+(15*3)`

I already create a function that take a list of lists and convert it to a list of tuples: 
From this `[[43525,3,2],[43615,2,2],[41111,1,2],[74855,5,3]]`
to this `[(3,2),(2,2),(1,2),(5,3)]`

```
    tupleInfo [[]] = []
    tupleInfo [[_,x,y]] = [(x,y)]
    tupleInfo list = map (\[_,x,y] -> (x,y)) list
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do two different things: first you want to turn the list of lists in a list of tuples, second you want to add `15*i` to the second element of each tuple. Let's try to write two different functions and then compose them together:

```
convertToTuples :: [[Int]] -> [(Int, Int)]
convertToTuples [[]] = []
convertToTuples xs = map (\[_, x, y] -> (x, y)) xs
```

If you take a closer look it is exactly as the fist version of `tupleInfo` you wrote except it removes the second case which is redundant: `map` already correctly handles that.

```
add15 :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]
add15 xs = zipWith (\idx (x, y) -> (x+15*idx, y)) [0..] xs
```

As you suggested it is pretty straightforward using the [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) function. Now you can obtain the solution by composing the two functions together:

```
solution :: [[Int]] -> [(Int, Int)]
solution xs = add15 (convertToTuples xs)
-- in a more Haskell-y way you could write:
-- solution = add15 . convertToTuples
```

I always prefer to decompose the domain logic in small self-contained functions that can then be composed, this way it is easier to reason about each step.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. I used the Zipwith function.

```
    tupleInfo [[]] = []
    tupleInfo [[_,x,y]] = [(x,y)]
    tupleInfo list =  zipWith (\[_,x,y] i -> (x+15*i,y)) list [0..]
```